# Rails Show value from a select box on change method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm trying to show a value from my model, when select box value changes.
my code it's like this.

```
<%= f.label :nit , "Client Nit:" %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:nit, Client.all, :nit, :nit, :prompt => "Select a  NIT")%>
```

My Client model has a name and a Nit, i need to display the value according to my Nit Selection For example:

I have in my table:

```
NIT=>Name

12345678=>John Doe

987654321=>Bruce Wayne

327654=>Clark Kent
```

If i choose the first one in the select box, i need to display "John Doe".

I'm trying to do this but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= f.collection_select(:nit, Client.all,:nit,:name,:prompt => "Select a NIT")%>
```